# How to print running commands for connected users in shell?

Tags: bash, shell

```
ps -ef | grep --color "ilir1477" | awk '{print $NF}'
```

Please explain to me.

Comment: What does _rulled_ mean? What do you need us to explain?

Comment: run commands* (for any user)

Comment: Really...still not getting you.

Comment: @Jayesh I think he means "print running commands". What's wrong with the command you're using? What is `ilir1477`? Is that a username?

Comment: yes, that is my user name. and i have to print running commands

Comment: @Barmar Ok..he need to `print some command` but exactly what problem he face from above code, i can't get it?

Comment: `ps -ef` doesn't print usernames, it prints numeric UID, so the `grep` can't work like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are after?

```
$ ps -u ilir1477 -o args=
```